Minecraft plugin chat text hover
I create minecraft chat filter plugin on version 1.18.2. I want to add text box on hover censured word but I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me, please?
package wojtus.wojtusChatmanagerPlugin;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.AsyncPlayerChatEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import wojtus.wojtusChatmanagerPlugin.utils.Colors;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class WojtusChatmanagerPlugin extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
        saveDefaultConfig();
        getLogger().info("Plugin Chatmanager został poprawnie uruchomiony!");
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onPlayerChat(AsyncPlayerChatEvent event) {
        String message = event.getMessage();
        FileConfiguration config = getConfig();
        String strippedMessage = message.replaceAll("(?i)§[0-9a-fk-or]", "");

        for (String word : config.getStringList("banned_words")) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(strippedMessage);

            while (matcher.find()) {
                String matchedWord = matcher.group();
                if (matchedWord.length() > 1) {
                    String censuredWord = matchedWord.charAt(0) + "*" +              matchedWord.substring(2);
                    censuredWord = "&c" + censuredWord + "&r";
                    message = message.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(matchedWord), censuredWord);
                }
            }
        }
        message = Colors.translate(message);
        event.setMessage(message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        getLogger().info("Plugin Chatmanager został poprawnie wyłączony!");
    }
}


Welcome on StackOverflow. Are you using paper ? Do you know what is adventure ?
